# Горячие клавиши в Linux

Tags: debian, hotkeys, xfce

У меня не работают в Android Studio часть хоткеев. Покопавшись в настройках оконного менеджера (у меня lightdm, xfce), обнаружил, что в нём эти хоткеи заняты. Можно как-нить сделать так, чтобы локальные хоткеи запущенной программы были приоритетнее глобальных ? то есть, чтобы хоткеи оконного менеджера работали, когда студия свёрнута или не запущена, а когда запущена, чтобы в студии работали ее хоткеи ? 
Такое поведение замечено не только в Android Studio.

Comment: нет, конечно. они потому и приоритетные, что глобальные. попробуйте просто убрать ненужные вам.

Comment: То есть, если нужны оба, придётся выбирать, что нужнее? тогда проще вобще все глобальные хоткеи отключить, и забыть их как страшный сон.